# Create a dynamic query using php inputs through dropdowns

Tags: drop-down-menu

I need to print data from database based on the selection in the dropdowns where three drops down lists are being shown. The user can select either one dropdown list or two or three based on his choice.But the should be based on the selected values in the selected dropdown lists. I'm new to php and I'm a learner. Can anyone sort out the problem here in my code.

if(isset($_POST['submt']))
        {

```
    $a = $_POST['prog'];
    $b = $_POST['cntr'];
    $c = $_POST['sectr'];

    $a1 = 'Programme_name';
    $b1 = 'Center_name';
    $c1 = 'Name_of_trade';

    $x=0; $y=0; $p=0; $q=0;

    if($a=='' && $b!='' && $c!='') { $x = $b1;  $y = $c1; $p = $b;  $q = $c; }
    if($b=='' && $c!='' && $a!='') { $x = $c1;  $y = $a1; $p = $c;  $q = $a; }
    if($c=='' && $a!='' && $b!='') { $x = $a1;  $y = $b1; $p = $a;  $q = $b; }


    echo $x." ".$y;
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","sherk005");
    mysql_select_db("erp");


    $hai = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_master_1 WHERE $x = '$p' AND $y = '$q'");

    while(mysql_fetch_row($hai)>0) {
    echo $hai['Partner_name'] . " " . $hai['Programme_name'];
    echo "<br>";
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably escape your variables in your query to get it right.

```
$hai = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_master_1 WHERE ".$x." = '".$p."' AND ".$y." = '".$q."'");
```

Consider also using mysqli functions as mysql are deprecated : http://php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: i get an error while i select the 2nd and 3rd drop downs and the values that are printed is those of 1st and 2nd's